# Removing individual elements using jQuery after they have been added to the page

Tags: jquery

Good day folks

I ran into a small issue while creating a basic shopping cart page. The issue is when I dynamically add teams to the shopping list, the "remove" button deletes ALL the teams not just the one it is appended to.

How can I get it so the 'remove' button only removes one element at a time? Thanks!

Here is the script I am using -

```
<script>
function removeTeam() {
    $("#teamAdded, .removeBtn").remove();
    $("br").remove();
    }  
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#submit').click(function(){
    var teamToAdd = $("#teamname").val();
    if(teamToAdd!==undefined && teamToAdd.length>0){
     var html = "<span id='teamAdded'>" + teamToAdd + "</span>" + "<button class='removeBtn' onClick='removeTeam();'>" + "Remove" + "</button>" + "<br>";
      $("#items").append(html);
    }
  });    
});  
</script>
```

Codepen link here: [Here](http://codepen.io/nballon/pen/Yqdvbz)

Comment: Of course, your code explicitly deletes all matching items, when it should take into account the item clicked (i.e. the `this` of the click event). Basically do not use inline `onclick=` handlers with dynamic items. Use a delegated event handler instead.

Comment: It also appears that your code is generating invalid HTML since all appended spans have the same id.  Id's should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following simplified HTML:

**HTML**

```
<input id="teamname">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Add">
<div id="items">

</div>
```

You can remove just the clicked on item this way:

**JQuery**

```
  $('#submit').on('click',function() {
    var teamToAdd = $("#teamname").val();
    $("#teamname").val('');
    if (teamToAdd !== undefined && teamToAdd.length > 0) {
      var html = "<div><span class='teamAdded'>" + teamToAdd + "</span>" + '<input type="button" class="removeBtn" value="Remove"></div>';
      $("#items").append(html);
    }
  });
$('#items').on('click', 'input', function (event) {
    console.log($(this).prev('span'));
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  });
```

**Some things to note**

- I removed the invalid HTML which was created by adding multiple
  elements with the same id.
- I changed the HTML you're adding by wrapping the elements in a div. 
  This removes the need for the `<br>` and simplifies the removal
  because now we only need to remove the div.
- I got rid of the inline handler and replaced it with a function that
  will bind to your dynamically added elements.
- When the Remove button is clicked, we look for the parent div for the
  clicked on button, and remove it.  This removes the individual
  element.

Here is a [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4oaho8t1/).

Comment: Thank you very much Devlin for the for the assistance!

Comment: @Noel - if the solution works for you, you can mark it as the answer using the checkmark